# Solidoodle 4 voltage requirements

Tags: printer-building, desktop-printer, electronics

I have a solidoodle 4 and have blown the power supply . Long and the short of it is I am trying to modify a Xbox 1 power supply to fulfill the need. I am measuring he voltage at the output and its 14.04 volt.

Question is this, is the operational voltage range on a solidoodle able to operate on 14 volt ?

Comment: Do you have the specifications of either the original power supply or the expected input voltage of the printer? There seem to be a complete void of information on this online, unfortunately. If you have the specifications at hand, it would be nice if you updated the question. Also, if you don't get any answers here, consider asking this question on the Electrical Engineering SE site as well.

Comment: Hi tormod, the original power supply was 12 volt

Comment: I don't know what the expected input voltage for the printer is.

Comment: As a follow up to this query, I am operating the printer now on the modified power supply , haven't done any really long prints as I am still working through the calibration process, had to move to a new computer as well, so I am restarting my setup from scratch. Main part is the Xbox one power supply works and does not appear to have any bad ramifications

Comment: I think I have accepted it.

Comment: Glad to hear that the information I dug up was able to help and worked out in the case of your new power supply! Happy printing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used or seen a solidoodle 4, but as found on the internet, the controller board used in the printer is a version of the Sanguinololu, and the reprap wiki says that

> The board is designed to be flexible in its power source, working with
>   a 12V/5V ATX power supply or any 7V-35V power source via the on-board
>   voltage regulator.

if you're using a board not older than V0.7 http://reprap.org/wiki/Sanguinololu

However, I have also found images that show the Solidoodle with this board:
http://www.reprap.org/wiki/SAV_MKI
which can be used with 11-15V. This however might be for older versions of the printer.

There are some things to keep in mind: if there is no voltage regulator on the board, make sure that all parts can take the voltage without overheating at some points.

Comment: Hi kamuro, thanks for the information, you had much more luck tracking down info than I did,  my printer is about 2 years old , pretty sure it's one of the newer ones but I will verify the firmware tonight . I decided after the old power supply went south I was going to try to upgrade it a bit to give some additional amps and the Xbox 1 power supply seems to fit the bill for the most part.